# Read until the server closes the connection

Tags: connection, go

I'm trying to read a JSON-encoded byte from a server, which will be indented, but of an unpredictable length, and no obvious termination byte. I would like to read the *entire* server response into a byte. The server will close the connection. Is it possible to do this using `net`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As a supplement to @minikomi 's answer, I would like to add that, if you are sure that the bytes returned from the server are JSON encoded, there's a nice package `encoding/json` for this.

http://golang.org/pkg/encoding/json/

If you are using a decoder to decode directly from a connection, sometimes the error won't be returned. You might want to use `fmt.Printf("%v\n", whateverDecodedFromTheConnection)` to see what the decoder gets for your struct when the connection is closed.

For example, in my case, where the `encoding/gob` decoder is used to decode a message from a tcp connection into a struct defined as:

```
type MessageType struct {
    Type uint8
}
```

When the connection is closed, `decoder.Decode(&buffer)` returns `{0}`. This might not be a common situation, but something needed to be watched out.

Answer (score 2):

Please have a look at the docs at http://golang.org/pkg/net/http/

An http [Get](http://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#Get) will return a [Response](http://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#Response) struct, which will have a Body of type `io.ReadCloser`.

You can then use [ioutil.ReadAll](http://golang.org/src/pkg/io/ioutil/ioutil.go?s=1139:1180#L30) to read the entire response to a byte array.

```
resp, err := http.Get("http://example.com/")
if err != nil {
    // handle error
}
defer resp.Body.Close()
body, err := ioutil.ReadAll(resp.Body)
```

Comment: This is very good to know, but unfortunately I'm not using `net/http`.